# get content of XML with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get a simple message from a response xml format; there is my 
Jquery code:

```
            ... 
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
```

"data" is my xml ,it is just something like: `<msg>OK</msg>`

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: _"I'm new here, please don't down vote"_ - If you're worried about downvotes, spend a bit more time writing a better question. If you already think you've written a good question don't worry about downvotes.

Comment: @AmitChotaliya:i get from mozilla debugger : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msg>ok</msg>

Comment: yes, it will work with that too, here is http://jsfiddle.net/XKSqs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use use [parseXml()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse the xml response and then you can use normal jquery functions on it. in you case

```
$($xml).find("msg").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
... 
dataType: 'xml',
success: function (data)
{
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
    alert(xmlDoc.find('msg').text());
}
```